# Redis pipeline as atomic

Tags: ruby, redis, atomic

Is there a way to have the following in a 1-request 1-response way?

given a redis set with key name and for each key has a redis hash with fields

How can I fetch the hashes of those keys in one go?

something like this, which is the best I can do (not sure this will work, but you get the idea)

```
hashes = []
keys = redis.smembers("myset")
redis.multi do  
  keys.map do |k|
   hashes << redis.hgetall(k)
  end
end
hashes = hash.map(&:value) # to resolve future values
```

but this does at least two requests (which isn't the best but ok), not sure how Redis::Future resolves to value (if it sends another request or not)

Answer (score 2):

No, Redis don't have a command which would return hashes for multiple keys* at once. You're stuck with n + 1 requests - one to get the keys, and one for each key.

You could try to write a Lua script, which to do all that in Redis and return the combined results. See the documentation of the [EVAL command](http://redis.io/commands/eval) for an introduction to scripting in Redis. Note that if you do this, you cannot use a cluster, as keys must be explicitly provided to the script for it to be safe in a cluster.

---

*[MGET](http://redis.io/commands/mget) does return values for multiple keys, but only if they're strings.

Comment: I was to understand that using multi does everything inside in one network request, no?

Comment: `MULTI` is a start of a transaction - it allows you to commit or rollback all changes at once, but they are still executed as separate calls to Redis.

Comment: Indeed, although generating key names or reading them from the DB (e.g., `smembers`) is against the recommendation of using the `KEYS' array argument to the Lua script and will be problematic to run on a sharded cluster